# Mapear array javascript y convertirlo en json

Tags: javascript, json, array

Estoy intentando mapear un array para generar un json como el que dibujo abajo, igual estoy planteándolo mal creando una lista primero.

```
// industries fk
            var industries = [];
            $.getJSON(urlHOST + '/crud/industries', function (data) {
                $.each(data.data, function (index) {
                    industries.push({
                        value: data.data[index].id,
                        label: data.data[index].description
                    });
                });
                console.log(industries)
            });
```

Esto me genera una lista tal que así:

```
0: {value: 1, label: "Manufacturing"}
1: {value: 2, label: "Energy & Tech"}
2: {value: 3, label: "Banking It&Ib"}
3: {value: 4, label: "CR&T"}
4: {value: 5, label: "Insurance"}
5: {value: 6, label: "Healthcare"}
6: {value: 7, label: "id2m Sector"}
```

Y necesito generar esto:

```
{ "1": "Manufacturing", "2": "Energy & Tech", "3": "Banking It&Ib", "4": "CR&T", "5": "Insurance", "6": "Healthcare", "7": "id2m Sector" }
```

Comment: ¿Quieres convertirlo en JSON o en un Objeto de JS?

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa en un objeto para tratarlo mas adelante en otro método.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que lo que recibes es un `Array` de `Objects` te recomiendo que uses el método `Array.prototype.reduce()`. De la siguiente forma:

- Luego iteras sobre el `Array` recibido con `reduce()`.
- En cada una de las iteraciones intertas en el objeto para la key 'value' el valor 'label'.
- Ya podrías trabajar con ese objeto.

```js
const list = [
  {value: 1, label: "Manufacturing"},
  {value: 2, label: "Energy & Tech"},
  {value: 3, label: "Banking It&Ib"},
  {value: 4, label: "CR&T"},
  {value: 5, label: "Insurance"},
  {value: 6, label: "Healthcare"},
  {value: 7, label: "id2m Sector"},
];

const myObj = list.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item['value']] = item.label
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(myObj);
```

Otra opción teniendo en cuenta tu código sería hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var industries = {};
$.getJSON(urlHOST + '/crud/industries', function (data) {
  $.each(data.data, function (index) {
    industries[data.data[index].id] = data.data[index].description
  });
  console.log(industries)
});
```

Y ya trabajarías con el objeto que necesitas.

Comment: Se podría usar `.reduce(...)` en lugar de `.forEach(...)` en el primer ejemplo, es una función especialmente pensada para lo que quiere hacer el OP

Comment: Justo acabo de caer en eso. Ahora lo edito. De todas formas la segunda parte me parece que se adecua perfectamente a lo que el OP pide

Comment: @PabloLozano muchísimas gracias por tu aportación, ya he editado la respuesta ;)

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa es justo lo que necesitaba, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa el metodo reduce, me ordena el objeto por la key, independientemente del orden que le llegue, he intentado ordenar el array previo con sort() pero el reduce me lo vuelve a ordenar, existe alguna via para evitar esto?, un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Me puedes poner un ejemplio?

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa https://jsfiddle.net/uva3sfy0/ esto es lo que estoy intentando.

Comment: Vale, ya lo he visto. No lo puedes evitar, no es algo propio de reduce, sino de cómo el navegador interpreta ese objeto, siempre te intentará ordenar las "keys" por orden, tanto numérico como alfabético. A efectos prácticos el objeto es exactamente el mismo.